# Set up proxy to handle CORS for arcgis js api

Tags: javascript, proxy, cors, arcgis-js-api

#### The prologue:

I am trying to pull a layer into my arcgis-js-api application and I'm having a hard time.  The layer is here:

https://maps.disasters.nasa.gov/ags04/rest/services/ca_fires_202008/sentinel2/MapServer

And I am trying to add it in this way:

```js
export const SC2Sept29 = new MapImageLayer({
    url:
        'https://maps.disasters.nasa.gov/ags04/rest/services/ca_fires_202008/sentinel2/MapServer/547',
});
```

When running my app, I get the classic CORS error

> Access to fetch at 'https://maps.disasters.nasa.gov/ags04/rest/services/ca_fires_202008/sentinel2/MapServer?f=json' from origin 'https://cdpn.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

This is coming from [this codepen](https://codepen.io/slutske22/pen/RwGwbgY?editors=1000), but the same happens when developing locally with [vscode live server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer), or webpack-dev-server.  This does not happen with other layers, just from layers on the maps.disasters.nasa.gov server.

#### trying to set up a proxy

I got some advice from the thread [CORS error when trying to access NASA layer](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-javascript/cors-error-when-trying-to-access-nasa-layer/m-p/1003964#M70880) that I need to set up a proxy for anything coming from this server.  Their advice was to follow [these instructions](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/proxies/) to set up a proxy, and to use one of arcgis's [ready-made proxies](https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy).  Personally, I am finding the instructions for the proxies repo to be lacking.  All of my experience in setting up server-side apps is with nodejs, and I am not understanding the instructions for how to do this.  The codepen I linked, for now, tries to use the [CORS anywhere proxy](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere) but setting it in the `esr/core/urlUtils`:

```js
urlUtils.addProxyRule({
  urlPrefix: 'maps.disasters.nasa.gov',
  proxyUrl: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com',
});
```

But this gives an error saying that `Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0`.  I can see in the network tab that the browser is indeed attempting to access the correct layer URL, correctly prefixed by the cors anywhere proxy URL.  But the response itself is just the text of the cors anywhere proxy, hence the error:

[image]

As I mentioned my dev environments are vscode live server and a webpack dev server, depending on what part of the app im building.  My target production environment is github pages - I didn't really expect this app to need a back end.  If I need a server side to provide a proxy, I can host it on heroku or even AWS as a full stack app.  When trying to use the pre-provided arcgis proxies, I get the same issue.  For example, I cloned their proxies repo to my directory:

[image]

When configuring `urlUtils` to refer to one of these proxies, it does so, but just returns the text content of the proxy file and gives me the `Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0` error.  There's a lot of chat on the esri forums about IIS, but I'm a mac guy and have no experience with that.  Esri offers proxies in .NET, java, or PHP, none of which I have experience in.

How can I get rid of these cors errors and properly pull layers from the nasa server into my app.  If I need a proxy, how can I set one up that will work for both my dev and production environments?  I have had a hard time finding tutorials at my level that apply to this scenario.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: Is the proxy working correctly? .. Try `http://[yourmachine]/PHP/proxy.php?ping` (if using PHP) to check it

Comment: When I try that endpoint my browser just downloads the .php file

Comment: I think you have a problem setting the proxy .. I just fork esri repository and added a docker and docker compose files to easy the set up .. https://github.com/cabesuon/resource-proxy .. check the main readme docker .. let me know when it works

Comment: I'm no master with docker, but I can't get this working.  Your readme command `sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.php.yml -d --build` doesn't work, I had to do `sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.php.yml -d build`, which doesn't run the containers, it just builds 2 images (php and resouce-web-proxy).  If I run a container on each of these manually, and then try the endpoint `http://localhost:8082/proxy?ping`, I get a 'This site can’t be reached' error...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am sorry I forgot the action `up`, my mistake,  the command should be `sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.php.yml up -d --build`, then if you list the containers (`sudo docker container ls`) you should have one for image `resource-proxy-web`, you should also see the port mapping and other info .. I will fix the readme later, let me know if it works and we continue

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. That command is working - it builds the images and launches the container. The `?ping` endpoint now works in the browser. Trying to access my layer's URL with the proxy prefix also works - responds with appropriate JSON.  However, in my test app, when applying that proxy url to the esri config using `urlUtils.addProxyRule`, I am still getting the CORS error, only now the url is prefixed with the proxy.  I am running my test app on localhost:5501 using vscode live server.   Any idea what might still be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think now we can summarize.

In order for this to work you need to set a proxy. Like you mention ESRI provides some implementations on different techs.

I fork their repository in order to include an easy test setup using docker and docker-compose. [resource-proxy fork](https://github.com/cabesuon/resource-proxy)

After clone it run,

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.php.yml up -d --build
```

Test proxy,

```
http://localhost:8082/proxy?ping
```

In their you will also find and example `nasa-service.html` that shows a correct configuration of the application and the proxy (all in PHP folder).

Just need to run `http://localhost:8082/nasa-service.html`.

The key thing here is that the application needs to be in the same origin that the proxy.

Comment: Your solution works.  I really appreciate your time.  Perhaps you can lead me a bit further?  I see that I indeed have to host this as a full stack app where I have control over a server-side proxy app (as opposed to static front end assets only).  That's fine, I can do that with heroku.  Your solution involves apache and php, neither of which I have experience with.  It would be nice to recreate your solution with cors-anywhere, but I'm struggling.  How might I either 1: recreate your solution with cors-anywhere, or 2: host your version of the proxy alongside my front end files on heroku?

Comment: I will give it a look tomorrow, I cant do it now sorry, and will comment you back

Comment: Thank you, I can't tell you how much I appreciate it.  As a primer, I am running an instance of [cors anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere) under `localhost:8089`.  My html is served from a vs-code live server at `localhost:5501`.  In my esri app, I put `proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:8089'`.  In the browser, the esri url has the prefix `'http://localhost:8089/?<nasa_url>'`, but returns a response containing the [cors anywhere text](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/), rather than the actual json for the map service.  Let me know what you think when you have time

Comment: Hi, I haven't been able to look in details yet, but one thing you need to remember is that both app and proxy should be in the same origin, and port number is part of it .. In you example both should be in localhost:5501 or both on localhost:8089 .. [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/origin)

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I'll take that into consideration.  I was able to pull that off, but still havig issues. I've been messing with this all day, and I thought that setting up a proxy with node warranted its own question: [CORS anywhere returning proxy text, not desired target resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65176887/cors-anywhere-returning-proxy-text-not-desired-target-resource)

Comment: Good, I will give it a look and ask it if I can. Glad I could help you a bit!