# CORS anywhere returning proxy text, not desired target resource

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, cors, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to set up a proxy using node, express, and an instance of [cors-anywhere](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere) for my arcgis-js-api app.  My server file looks like this:

```js
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import corsAnywhere from 'cors-anywhere';

const { PORT } = process.env;
const port = PORT || 3030;

var app = express();

let proxy = corsAnywhere.createServer({
    originWhitelist: [], // Allow all origins
    requireHeaders: [], // Do not require any headers.
    removeHeaders: [], // Do not remove any headers.
});

app.use(cors());

app.get('/proxy/:proxyUrl*', (req, res) => {
    req.url = req.url.replace('/proxy/', '/');
    proxy.emit('request', req, res);
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

When I go to `http://localhost:3030/proxy/https://maps.disasters.nasa.gov/ags04/rest/services/ca_fires_202008/sentinel2/MapServer?f=json`, I get to my target json no problem, with `access-control-allow-origin: *` correctly tacked on.

In my front end html (an arcgis-js-api app), I am calling that same url:

```
var layer = new MapImageLayer({
  url: 'http://localhost:3030/proxy/https://maps.disasters.nasa.gov/ags04/rest/services/ca_fires_202008/sentinel2/MapServer?f=json',
});
```

My network tab shows a response not of the expected JSON, but of the text of the cors-anywhere proxy:

[image]

For those familiar with the arcgis-js-api, you can also preconfigure use of a proxy:

```
urlUtils.addProxyRule({
  urlPrefix: 'maps.disasters.nasa.gov',
  proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:3030/proxy/',
});
```

If I do it this way, the network tab shows that the call to the `localhost:3030/proxy/<url>` is returning the index.html page, not the desired json.

Why is the proxy giving the expected/required result when I access the url directly through the browser, but not when being called from my front end file?  Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the browser console and noticed that the url being sent to the proxy instead of this

http://localhost:3030/proxy/https://maps.disasters.nasa.gov/ags04/rest/services/ca_fires_202008/sentinel2/MapServer?f=json

looks like this

http://localhost:3030/proxy/https:/maps.disasters.nasa.gov/ags04/rest/services/ca_fires_202008/sentinel2/MapServer?f=json

Not sure why it's happening, but as a quick fix you can replace

```
req.url = req.url.replace('/proxy/', '/');
```

with

```
req.url = req.url.replace('/proxy/https:/', '/https://');
```

[image]

Comment: That is ***so*** weird - but amazing catch!  I tried this and now I am not getting any cors errors, and my JSON response is as expected.  After a moment, the app calls for the image, but the delay is long and I get a 502 bad gateway error.  Would you mind sharing the code you used to create the screenshot you posted?  Thank you so much btw

Comment: I'm also getting 502 error. The issue is on their side.

Comment: You're welcome. Here is the code https://anatolysukhanov.com/stackoverflow/arcgis/server.js https://anatolysukhanov.com/stackoverflow/arcgis/client.html

Comment: I checked a bunch of their other layers on arcgis online, they're all down right now.  Of course, right as soon as I get a working answer!  Thanks again friend